# Can you complete the Galactic Wars game?

Tags: candy-box-2

There is a simulation in game called 'Galactic Wars' which can be unlocked once you get the key to the 3rd house.

What is the purpose of this game? Has anyone managed to complete it because I get killed at Level 3 each time

Answer (score 2):

This game is only played for candies. There is no end, so you can't "complete" it.

According to [Galactic Wars](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=galactic_wars) on the official wiki, this is the formula for calculating the number of candies earned:

```
 candies earned = maximum(score, 31*score - 30000)
```

Comment: If you're happy with this answer, please mark it as accepted.